# Pandas to_csv with escape characters and other junk causing return to next line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that has a bunch of manually entered text, some of which contains various escape characters.

Currently, there are a couple of lines where the output creates a new row. The one that is causing the most problems are the `<br/>` in the middle and at the end of the text. I'm looking to clean the text just enough so that a new line is not created

EDIT
Here's some examples of strings that are causing problems

```
Example<br/>
Example sentence (number two)\r<br/>That caused an issue
```

Comment: can you post a few lines of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using converters for the read_csv, adapt the example below to your needs:

```
def remove_br(x):
    return x.replace('<br \>','')

convert_dict = {'col_name':remove_br}

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters=converter_dict)
```