# Pandas to_csv adds new rows when data has special characters

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

My data has multiple columns including a text column

```
id                 text                                                      date 

8950026    Make your EMI payments only through ABC                  01-04-2021 07:43:54
8950969    Pay from your Bank Account linked on XXL \r              01-04-2021 02:16:48 
8953627    Do not share it with anyone. -\r                         01-04-2021 08:04:57
```

I used pandas to_csv to export my data. That works well for my first row but for the next 2 rows, it creates a new line and moves the date to the next line and adds to the total rows. Basically my output csv will have 5 rows instead of 3

```
df_in.to_csv("data.csv", index = False)
```

What is the best way to handle the special character "\r" here? I tried converting the text variable to string in pandas (Its dtype is object now) but that doesn't help . I can try and remove all \r in the end of text in my dataframe before exporting, but is there a way to modify to_csv to export this in the right format ?

**** EDIT****
This question below is similar and I can solve the problem by replacing all instances of \r in my dataframe but how can this be solved by not replacing? Does to_csv have options to handle these

[Pandas to_csv with escape characters and other junk causing return to next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538471/pandas-to-csv-with-escape-characters-and-other-junk-causing-return-to-next-line)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas to\_csv with escape characters and other junk causing return to next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538471/pandas-to-csv-with-escape-characters-and-other-junk-causing-return-to-next-line)

Comment: thats for read_csv. Is there a way to do during exporting ```to_csv``` ? I could apply the replace function in dataframe but I am wondering if there is a better solution as there could be other characters in the end that can create this issue